# Inserting values in a list in a list

Tags: python

So i have

```
matrix = [['B Borg', '3', '3', '1.0'], ['F Perry', '7', '8', '0.875'], ['R Nadal', '3', '5', '0.6']]
```

I want to make it look like this:

```
[['1','B Borg', '3', '3', '1.0'], ['2','F Perry', '7', '8', '0.875'], ['3','R Nadal', '3', '5', '0.6']]
```

I've tried

```
matrix.insert([0][0],"1")
matrix.insert([1][0],"2")
matrix.insert([2][0],"3")
```

But the end result is:

```
matrix = ["1",",2","3"['B Borg', '3', '3', '1.0'], ['F Perry', '7', '8', '0.875'], ['R Nadal', '3', '5', '0.6']]
```

My guess is that i messed up the indexing in the insert part, but i just cannot figure out what i did wrong.

Answer (score 5):

The problem is that `[0][0]` is the first element in the list `[0]`—that is, `0`. So, `matrix.insert([0][0], "1")` is the same as `matrix.insert(0, "1")`. In other words, it inserts a new row at the top of the matrix, with only a single value, `"1"`.

What you want is `matrix[0].insert(0, "1")`. Since `matrix[0]` is the first row in the matrix, this inserts a new column at the left end of the first row.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
matrix2 = [[str(i+1)] + x for i,x in enumerate(matrix)]
```

Answer (score 0):

```
>>> matrix = [[str(i)]+subl for i,subl in enumerate(matrix, 1)]
>>> matrix
[['1', 'B Borg', '3', '3', '1.0'], ['2', 'F Perry', '7', '8', '0.875'], ['3', 'R Nadal', '3', '5', '0.6']]
```

Or, use the consume itertools recipe:

```
>>> matrix = [['B Borg', '3', '3', '1.0'], ['F Perry', '7', '8', '0.875'], ['R Nadal', '3', '5', '0.6']]
>>> collections.deque((subl.insert(0, str(i)) for i,subl in enumerate(matrix, 1)), maxlen=0)
deque([], maxlen=0)
>>> matrix
[['1', 'B Borg', '3', '3', '1.0'], ['2', 'F Perry', '7', '8', '0.875'], ['3', 'R Nadal', '3', '5', '0.6']]
```

Answer (score 0):

If you loop over the matrix, the items will be the things you need to insert into

```
>>> matrix = [['B Borg', '3', '3', '1.0'], ['F Perry', '7', '8', '0.875'], ['R Nadal', '3', '5', '0.6']]
>>> for i, item in enumerate(matrix, 1):
...     item.insert(0, str(i))
... 
>>> matrix
[['1', 'B Borg', '3', '3', '1.0'], ['2', 'F Perry', '7', '8', '0.875'], ['3', 'R Nadal', '3', '5', '0.6']]
```